# Combining queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've the following queries:

Query 1

```
SELECT so.ClientID, 'All Channels' as CustomerGroup, so.StatementID, so.Brand, so.Product,
Sum(so.Amount) Amount, Sum(so.Value_CP) Value_CP
into #t1
FROM RG_SalesOut_Report so
WHERE so.Block=0 AND so.[All Sources]='SalesOUT'AND so.Value_CP>0 AND so.Amount>0 AND
so.Brand in('Brand 1', 'Brand 2')
GROUP BY so.ClientID, so.CustomerGroup, so.StatementID, so.Brand, so.Product
```

Query 2

```
select t1.ClientID, t1.CustomerGroup, t1.StatementID, t1.Brand, t1.Product,
Sum(t1.Amount) AS Amount, Sum(t1.Value_CP) AS Value_CP
into #t2
from #t1 t1
group by t1.ClientID, t1.CustomerGroup, t1.StatementID, t1.Brand, t1.Product
```

Query 3

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by t2.ClientID desc) as ID, *, CONCAT(t2.ClientID, t2.Product) AS Code
into #t3
from #t2 t2
group by t2.ClientID, t2.CustomerGroup, t2.StatementID, t2.Brand, t2.Product, t2.Amount, t2.Value_CP, CONCAT(t2.ClientID, t2.Product)
ORDER BY t2.ClientID DESC, t2.Product, t2.StatementID desc
```

Query 4

```
select tab1.ClientID, tab1.CustomerGroup, convert(varchar,(CONVERT(date,tab1.StatementID,104)),104) AS StatementID, tab1.Brand,
tab1.Product, tab1.Amount, tab1.Value_CP, IIF(tab1.code=tab2.code, DATEDIFF(MONTH,tab2.StatementID, tab1.StatementID), 0) AS M_SALES
FROM #t3 tab1
RIGHT JOIN #t3 tab2
ON tab1.ID=tab2.ID-1
where tab1.StatementID >= '01.01.2013'
order by tab1.ID asc
```

How to merge them into one query?
I need Query 4 results

Comment: use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` between your query if you want to keep duplicates (if any)

Comment: Union?  As long as all queries are returning the same columns, use a UNION statement in betwern the queries to have them return a single result set with all the data.

Comment: Can everyone please **stop edit-vandalizing this post**? I'll fix it now, then kindly stop cluttering it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you use SQLServer you can use [Common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) without temp tables insert. Also you don't need `order by` class in the #T3 query:

```
WITH T1 AS 
(
SELECT so.ClientID, 'All Channels' as CustomerGroup, so.StatementID, so.Brand, so.Product,
Sum(so.Amount) Amount, Sum(so.Value_CP) Value_CP
FROM RG_SalesOut_Report so
WHERE so.Block=0 AND so.[All Sources]='SalesOUT'AND so.Value_CP>0 AND so.Amount>0 AND
so.Brand in('Brand 1', 'Brand 2')
GROUP BY so.ClientID, so.CustomerGroup, so.StatementID, so.Brand, so.Product 
),
T2 AS
(
select t1.ClientID, t1.CustomerGroup, t1.StatementID, t1.Brand, t1.Product,
Sum(t1.Amount) AS Amount, Sum(t1.Value_CP) AS Value_CP
from T1
group by t1.ClientID, t1.CustomerGroup, t1.StatementID, t1.Brand, t1.Product
),
T3 AS
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by t2.ClientID desc) as ID, *, CONCAT(t2.ClientID, t2.Product) AS Code
from t2
group by t2.ClientID, t2.CustomerGroup, t2.StatementID, t2.Brand, t2.Product, t2.Amount, t2.Value_CP, CONCAT(t2.ClientID, t2.Product)
)

select tab1.ClientID, tab1.CustomerGroup, convert(varchar,(CONVERT(date,tab1.StatementID,104)),104) AS StatementID, tab1.Brand,
tab1.Product, tab1.Amount, tab1.Value_CP, IIF(tab1.code=tab2.code, DATEDIFF(MONTH,tab2.StatementID, tab1.StatementID), 0) AS M_SALES
FROM T3 tab1
RIGHT JOIN T3 tab2
ON tab1.ID=tab2.ID-1
where tab1.StatementID >= '01.01.2013'
order by tab1.ID asc
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm using SQL Server 2012, I've to use `order by` in the #T3, because I getting wrong data in calculated field (M_Sales). Do you have any idea?

Comment: The order of #T3 is completely irrelevant - your join is based on the result of `ROW_NUMBER() over(order by t2.ClientID desc)`. This is what affects your results - if they are not what you expect then you need to alter the order by within this function. Since we don't know what you currently have, why it is wrong, and what you are expecting, it is pretty hard to suggest a correction.